# copy of objects : proper way to copy the random engine

Tags: c++, random

I wrote a cpp class that generates a random process.
I defined the random engine as a public attribute of my class.

My question is : what happens with the engine when I use the operator= :

```
Proc A; 
// operations on A 
Proc B;
B=A;
```

will it create a new engine for B initialised randomly ? Or will it create a engine that will generate pseudo-random numbers from where the engine of A stopped ?

Here is how I wrote the class :

```
class Proc {
  public:
mt19937 eng {random_device{}()};
double Tps;
vector<int> prc;
... }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you define an `operator=` for your class or are you using the default one?

Comment: The default assignment operator will copy the state of the mersenne twister member, which will deliver the same sequence of random numbers from that point on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 0):

Search for implicit copy constructor

> The implicit
>   copy constructor does a member-wise copy of the source object

[Copy constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/)

Answer (score 0):

The default copy assignment operator (as well as the default copy constructor) will just copy the whole `mt19937` with all its internal state, so both instances will get the same sequence of random numbers.

One solution would be to reseed on every copy by designing a suitable assignment operator and copy constructor. This might take some time if you make many copy, especially if really want to produce a 19937 bit seed every time.

The other possibility would be a `private static thread_local` generator shared by all instances. That would get rid of the seeding problem and is probably the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My first idea was actually to declare my engine as local. I wanted to do write something like : 
    "static m19937 eng {...} "
as one attribute of the class Proc.  But it doesnt compile. 
Can you please tell me how to declare the engine as static in my class ? Thanks !

Comment: Actually what do you mean by "both instances will get the same sequence of random numbers.". When I do some tests like A=B; cout << A.random() << B.random() << endl; where random is a method of Proc written as:     double random() {
        uniform_real_distribution<>dis(1,2);
        return dis(eng);
    }
The results not similar at all. Looks like the results are "not correlated".

Comment: @CômeHuré Cannot reproduce that. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e9b2adbf01cfd58 the distribution does not change that. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca54fdadf78f20fb

Comment: @CômeHuré And for your first comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63e7def3112b6586

Comment: It's very strange. I copied and compiled your cpp on my mac and a linux server : the assert failed in both during both of the executions of the outputs.

Comment: Thank you for the second code you posted to me : my g++ on mac don't want to compile it, but it compiles well on my linux

Comment: @CômeHuré *"the assert failed in both during both of the executions of the outputs"* That really should not happen, what I stated in my answer is what the standard says. Might be worth posting a question for that (including information on what implementation you use), maybe someone can point you to a bug report. Tbh, I do not quite see how that would happen.

Comment: @CômeHuré *"my g++ on mac don't want to compile it"* Maybe it's too old, `thread_local` is C++11. If your code is not multithreaded anyways, you can just drop it.

Comment: I noticed I mixed the cpp files up when I did the tests yesterday... As you said, the 2 copied generators draw the same pseudo random numbers.

Comment: my mac compiled the file well when I removed the "thread_local" terms. Thanks a lot for the help.